# I am having a hard time turning this nested terniary operator code to if-else statements

Tags: javascript

```
function timeConversion(s) {

  const arr = s.slice(0, 8).split(":");

  arr[0] =

    s.indexOf("PM") > -1

      ? arr[0] == 12

        ? "12"

        : Number(arr[0]) + 12

      : arr[0] == 12

      ? "00"

      : arr[0];

  let result = arr.join(":");

  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It becomes a bit more readable if you could indent it better like below:

```js
function timeConversion(s) {

  const arr = s.slice(0, 8).split(":");

  arr[0] =
    s.indexOf("PM") > -1
      ? arr[0] == 12
        ? "12"
        : Number(arr[0]) + 12
      : arr[0] == 12
        ? "00"
        : arr[0];

  let result = arr.join(":");

  console.log(result);
}
```

Now we can write the if-else statement for this like below:

```js
function timeConversion(s) {

  const arr = s.slice(0, 8).split(":");

  if (s.indexOf("PM") > -1) {
    if (arr[0] == 12) {
      arr[0] = "12";
    } else {
      arr[0] = Number(arr[0]) + 12
    }
  } else if (arr[0] == 12) {
    arr[0] = "00";
  }

  let result = arr.join(":");

  console.log(result);
}
```